# How do you open a link in a popup window in edge animate

Tags: adobe-edge

I have a link to a URL for an external webpage in my adobe edge composition. How do I get that link to open the external HTML page in a popup window?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think this is what you are looking for:

Add this to a Click action on the button you want to press that will drive you to the new page.

```
window.open("http://yourURL.com", "_blank");
```

I hope that helps.

Adam